# AX 2009 Check (Cheque) Logo Not Printing Correctly

Tags: axapta

We've got a .gif image with a transparent background set as the logo in AX 2009. When we print checks *some* of our user's get checks with the transparent background portion of the logo printed black.  The same is true of the check signature.

If I print the GIF directly to the same printer, it prints fine (no black in the transparent portion of the image)

This leads me to believe it is a user setting in AX, considering it only occurs for some of our users and that the raw gif prints just fine.

I see the logo gets stored in the BANKCHEQUELAYOUT table in a data type *image* field. It looks like that is an AX-wide record (not per user) so I don't think the issue is with that value.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Are there user-level print settings I should look at?

Comment: Have you tried to understand if this is somehow related to windows themes? Ax is setup to follow windows themes as well so...just a thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this nailed down, Thanks to Jan's comment. Here are the steps I took:

1. Create a .gif image with a white background.
2. Change the BackStyle property of the image in the check report to **Opaque**.
3. In the showLogo method of the CompanyImage form, add this line of code:

logoImage.transparent(true,255,255,255);

so the complete showLogo method looks like:

```
void  showLogo()
```

{

```
Image   logoImage;
;
try
{
    element.lock();
    if (imageContainer)
    {
        logoImage = new Image();
        logoImage.setData(imageContainer);
        logoImage.transparent(true,255,255,255);
        image.image(logoImage);
        image.widthValue(logoImage.width());
        image.heightValue(logoImage.height());
    }
    else
    {
        image.imageResource(0);
        image.widthValue(32);
        image.heightValue(32);
    }

    element.resetSize();
    element.unLock();
}
catch (Exception::Warning)
{
    throw error(strfmt("@SYS19312", imageFilePathName));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the `BackStyle` property of the the bitmap control is set to `Transparent`. This is a mandatory step to enable transparency of any report or form image control.

I have not tried transparency with GIF image files. However GIF was not a supported image file in previous versions of AX, maybe there is an error with transparency.

My first suggestion is to convert the GIF to PNG, update the image in the check layout and try again.

My second option would be to remove transparency and replace with the background color (white?).

**Update**: AX stores images in the `CompanyImage` table. The size of the images can be calculated by implementing this method:

```
display ImageSize imageSize()
{
    ImageSize size;
    BinData b;
    if (this.Image)
    {
        b = new BinData();
        b.setData(this.Image);
        size = b.size();
    }
    return size;
}
```

Unfortunately `new Image(this.Image).size()` does not work. Drag the method to the `AutoReport` field group, then open the table in the table browser.

In my example the PNG file had the size 1476 bytes and the BMP file 42062 bytes.

Comment: BackStyle is set to transparent. Also the only file types it will accept are .bmp, .gif, .jpg and .jpeg. PNG's are not allowed. I tried each file type and the same problem occurs. I think AX converts it to a .bmp before storing it in the database no matter what file type you use

Comment: PNG is supported by AX, but not by CompanyImage. You can change this in \Forms\CompanyImage\Designs\Design\[Group:GroupImage]\[ButtonGroup:ButtonGroup]\Button:Change\Methods\clicked

Comment: Ok thank you. I added .png to the list, changed it to .png and it still prints with a black background. I see how you used the size to point out that it doesn't convert to bmp. I'm going to play around with the check report more, with it set as a png and see what happens.

Comment: It's interesting. I can print to my physical printer, CutePDF (which prints to a PDF file), Send to OneNote (which adds to the printout to a OneNote document) and no matter what it always comes out black.  Also, when I use Print Test, I can right click the image in the preview, copy the image, and paste it into Paint.NET and it's black there too.

Comment: What color did you choose as your transparent color?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You mean in the actual png image? The bg on that is just transparent. Here is a screenshot of the check report along with the properties of the image in question. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/checkreport.png/   I really appreciate the help!